# A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION".EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION

Tags: 2011-sp1

When I am trying to access some of the Publications in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, I am getting below error message details. Can anyone help in resolving this issue?

We have already restarted the CMS server and services. Also gathered stats in Oracle database but still getting the same error.

> (8004033F) ORA-08103: object no longer exists
>   ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.EDA_PUBLICATIONS", line 91
>   ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.EDA_PUBLICATIONS", line 1339
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>   Unable to get list of SDL Tridion Content Manager items.
>   A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION".EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION

Comment: Seems like your database is corrupted. Did anyone update or touch it recently?

Comment: Thanks Andrey for reply. Database was not touched. We have just gathered stats in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the DB has been corrupted. There are a couple of options that you have:

**Best Case Scenario:** If you have a primary and a secondary setup for the DB, then try failing over to the secondary node and hopefully that won't be corrupted like the primary one and then this error should go away. Same is true if DB recently failed over to Secondary node and that might be corrupted, then try failing back to primary

**Worst Case Scenario** Check your DB backups and try to restore from the most recent backup. This means that you are going to loose some data (anything after the backup)

Comment: Yep. This is what I found quickly - http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=21197

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your reply.

Issue is resolved now and here is the solution which I followed :-

All of the CMS database package were valid but one of the procedure (EDA_PUBLICATIONS.READ_PUBLICATION) status changed to invalid in oracle buffer cache.

Issue is resolved after flushing oracle cache.

Commands executed:-

SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.